# Setting image resource to RecyclerView list items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-cardview

I'm trying to set an image for each `CardView` item in my `RecyclerView`.

Here's my `onBindViewHolder` :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Masar masar=masrList.get(position);
    holder.masarName.setText(masar.getMasarTitle());
    holder.masarDesc.setText(masar.getMasarDescreption());

    // why i'm getting error here
    holder.masarImg.setImageDrawable(masar.getMasarImg());
}
```

And here's my class model:

```
public class Masar {
    public String masarTitle;
    public String masarDescreption;
    public int masarImg;

    public Masar(String masarTitle, String masarDescreption) {
        this.masarTitle = masarTitle;
        this.masarDescreption = masarDescreption;
    }

    public Masar(String masarTitle, String masarDescreption, int masarImg) {
        this.masarTitle = masarTitle;
        this.masarDescreption = masarDescreption;
        this.masarImg = masarImg;
    }

    public String getMasarTitle() {
        return masarTitle;
    }

    public String getMasarDescreption() {
        return masarDescreption;
    }

    public int getMasarImg() {
        return masarImg;
    }

    public void setMasarImg(int masarImg) {
        this.masarImg = masarImg;
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me why I'm getting error?

And what's the right method to do it?

Comment: what value did you pass in`'setImageDrawable()` method?

Comment: post your error log here as well

Comment: the error log is : setImageDrawable can't be applied to int .
i'm passing int to it , int[] masa = new int[]{
                R.drawable.jenen,
                R.drawable.qalt,
                R.drawable.m1,
                R.drawable.m1,
        };
@akhilesh0707

Comment: try this `setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(masar.getMasarImg()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `holder.masarImg.setImageDrawable(masar.getMasarImg());`

Use

```
holder.masarImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(masar.getMasarImg()));
```

or

```
holder.masarImg.setImageResource(masar.getMasarImg());
```

**Note:** to get `getResources()` use `context`

Comment: @YousefAhmad  try `holder.masarImg.getContext().getResources()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) `

```
             Glide.with(context)
            .load(where image live)
            .into(holder.your imageview);`
```

Answer (score 1):

@akhilesh0707's second option is to do as follows:

```
holder.masarImg.setImageResource(masar.getMasarImg());
```

but I needed a Kotlin solution so I modified it and this is working for me:

```
holder.masarImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.myfile.png)
```

Hope it helps someone as I wasted hours on trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `holder.masarImg.setImageResource(masar.getMasarImg());` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to set an image to an ImageView, via a Drawable or a Resource Id.
You are using setImageDrawable which expects a type of Drawable yet you are passing an int with getMasarImg().  If you have the image resource id (which IS an int) then you can set the image this way using setImageResouce() instead.  Of course you can also use getResources().getDrawable(an INT resource here) instead but this is deprecated (if I remember correctly) so use ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), your drawable here) as a replacement.
Most of the time I will use the ContextCompat way to get my drawable but remember you need to the context - getActivity() - to use this and as you are in a RecyclerView adapter you will not have the context so you will have to pass it in the constructor.